# Default constructor implementation in a trait

Tags: rust, traits

`Point` and `Vec2` are defined with the same variable and exactly the same constructor function:

```rust
pub struct Point {
    pub x: f32,
    pub y: f32,
}

pub struct Vec2 {
    pub x: f32,
    pub y: f32,
}

impl Point {
    pub fn new(x: f32, y: f32) -> Self {
        Self { x, y }
    }
}

impl Vec2 {
    pub fn new(x: f32, y: f32) -> Self {
        Self { x, y }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to define a trait to implement the constructor function?

So far I found it only possible to define the interface as the internal variables are not known:

```rust
pub trait TwoDimensional {
    fn new(x: f32, y: f32) -> Self;
}
```

Comment: it's completely impossible and wouldn't make anysense

Comment: If your goal is to reduce duplication by only implementing one function that works for both `Point` and `Vec2`, I don't think that's possible. There's no way to abstract the struct literal syntax needed to construct the different types.

Comment: You may be interested by https://docs.rs/derive-new/0.5.9/derive_new/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately no, you can defined default trait impls but since a trait cannot make any assumptions about the type it is being implemented on, you cannot operate directly on any of its fields.

Answer (score 5):

You can certainly define such a trait, and implement it for your 2 structs, but you will have to write the implementation twice. Even though traits can provide default implementations for functions, the following won't work:

```rust
trait TwoDimensional {
  fn new(x: f32, y: f32) -> Self {
    Self {
      x,
      y,
    }
  }
}
```

The reason why is fairly simple. What happens if you implement this trait for `i32` or `()` or an `enum`?

Traits fundamentally don't have information about the underlying data structure that implements them. Rust does not support OOP, and trying to force it often leads to ugly, unidiomatic and less performant code.

If however, you have a bunch of structs and want to essentially "write the same `impl` multiple times without copy/pasting", a macro might be useful. This pattern is common in the standard library, where, for example, there are certain functions that are implemented for all integer types. For example:

```rust
macro_rules! impl_constructor {
  ($name:ty) => {
    impl $name {
      pub fn new(x: f32, y: f32) -> Self {
        Self {
          x, y
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

impl_constructor!(Point);
impl_constructor!(Vec2);
```

These macros expand at compile time, so if you do something invalid (e.g. `impl_constructor!(i32)`, you'll get a compilation error, since the macro expansion woudl contain `i32 { x, y }`.

Personally I only use a macro when there is really a large number of types that need an implementation. This is just personal preference however, there is no runtime difference between a hand-written and a macro-generated `impl` block.